firebase js en firebase hosting
cuando intento usar un ejemplo con firebase auth, utilizando firebase hosting no me carga los módulos, me arroja el siguiente error:
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "firebase/auth". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Sigo paso por paso las instrucciones, pero tengo entendido que el error es por que no me carga los moduos.
